# Color change of echo in php based on calculation

Tags: php

How can you change color of an echo to be red if calculation result is under 10% ? I've provided a sample of my PHP code below. Thank you in advance for your help.

```
<td '$value= .round(100 * ($data[$tabele[$i]][$keys[$tabele[$i]][0]] + $data[$tabele[$i]]["RESERVED"] + $data[$tabele[$i]]["BIZ_AVAILABLE"]) / ArraySum($data[$tabele[$i]]) ,2).'% 'if ($value<10)'<td style="color: red;"</td>
```

Comment: Can you share what you've tried?

Comment: I am beginner,i tryed with if and else but i just broke code.

Comment: You can do it with an if-else condition. Edit: So post here what you've tried so far, then we will help you to find your errors.

Comment: You should probably separate your code from the presentation to help make the process a bit more lucid. For example, for a very basic starter, 1. split up that hilariously long echo; 2. do your math for each line before you echo something; and 3. then simply choose the color based on your result. You can't change it after you've already defined it in your inline CSS.

Comment: Markus, can you give me example ? So i can learn. Thank you for your time.

Comment: I tried this way but did not give resoults.